# A team lead of another project keeps assigning his project, despite knowing that I am in a different one

Tags: job-description

I started a project 1 did it almost alone. After a certain section of it was completed, I started with Project 2. This Project 2 has a different team lead. It took 1 month for Project 2, and since Project 1's deployment was coming near, I told the team lead 2 that I need to work on Project 1. Moreover, there were some changes in Project 1 as proposed by the client. So, I denied some major changes within the available time, while I told that I can complete the smaller ones before the launch date.

However, the team lead from Project 2 keeps bothering me with the issues/changes that he faces with the Project 2. Even though I say, I dont have time, he asks me to give extra effort (that means overtime). I am unable to handle both these projects simultaneously, especially because Project 1 is to be launched soon. **What should I do ?**

Comment: What does your line manager say you should be working on?

Comment: @PhilipKendall He doesn't bother.

Comment: Don't use that as an excuse, just ask your manager directly "should I be working on Project 1 or Project 2?"

Comment: I kept asking him. He told me to do both projects. These were his exact words in first person

Comment: then you either do what your boss told you to do or don't.

Answer (score 2):

> What should I do ?

You should make sure you know what you're meant to be working on.

That typically involves dialogue with your line manager, your to-do lists, and whatever else.

---

**EDIT:** Okay, OP has since revealed that the line manager has told him to do both projects 1 and 2. So that's what OP should do.

Of course, OP can manage expectations, and say things like "if I'm doing both projects, that's going to affect deadline X in this way, or we can leave out features Y and Z to try and get both things done in time". But the details are scarce enough it's hard to give a real answer.

Comment: He doesn't bother.

Comment: @Skumar Who doesn't bother with what?

Comment: The Reporting Manager (who oversees both the projects)

Comment: Come on, what does the reporting manager not bother to do?